# How to split EPUB XHTML pages dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, xhtml, split, epub

I extracted EPUB files to XHTML and showed them on WebView. But when I want to show them on WebView, it shows whole page. So it is not look like a book. I want to split pages specify according to screen size. Is it possible? Or how can EPUB viewers parse the pages and show only a part of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your solution if you have done successfully ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to implement ebook pagination in a web browser is to use [CSS3 columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/), make each column the width of the viewport, and slide the content back and forth across the viewport as the user pages right or left. The open-source ereader Readium is [an example of this implementation](http://readium.github.io/readium-viewer-demo1/).